# How to get reference to object in Delphi Debugger Visualizer?

Tags: delphi, debugging, ide

I'm writing a debugger visualizer for certain object type, but I can't figure out how to get the debugged object.
I use `IOTADebuggerServices` to `Evaluate`, but result is always a `string` and I want a reference to the `Object` (of type that visualizer works for)

Anyone knows how to get the reference to object ?

Comment: There are several visualizer source files that ship with Delphi, in the Source\Visualizers folder that should help.

Comment: You can `Evaluate` the current expression to get the memory address of the object, which yes will be reported as a `string`. Simply convert that string to an integer with `StrToInt/64()` and then type-cast that integer to the actual class type.